# Invoke Curl from within shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I've below code in shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

oauth_consumer_key='sdfsfsd'
oauth_consumer_key_secret='1sdfsdfs1'
oauth_token='5wrwerwr476a1737fe09de2e4ew'
oauth_token_secret='ec2231779e4'

url='https url goes here'

token=$(./oauth $oauth_consumer_key $oauth_consumer_key_secret $oauth_token $oauth_token_secret GET $url)

curl_path='/usr/bin/curl'
curl_args="-H 'Authorization: $token'"

resp=$($curl_path $curl_args $url)

echo $resp
```

Here, I'm first running oauth.sh from this program by passing params & capturing output in token which works as expected. And this output looks as shown below:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="45435", oauth_token="4r43", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1415328827", oauth_nonce="4535345", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="bKeewO%2BTJ7IHjurhtaftn9dNfxA%3D"' 'my url goes here'
```

Now, I need to invoke curl command from this program by passing above as param as shown below:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="45435", oauth_token="4r43", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1415328827", oauth_nonce="4535345", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="bKeewO%2BTJ7IHjurhtaftn9dNfxA%3D"' 'my url goes here'
```

When I run above curl command from terminal console, it works but from my shell script it gives error `couldn't resolve OAuth`

Can anyone help me out in fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this line is looking for "oauth" in the current directory.

```
token=$(./oauth
```

I would try putting the absolute path to oauth instead of ./oauth and see if that works.

If that doesn't work, I would strip it down a little and comment out everything after that line and just echo $token and see if it's showing the expected results and go from there.

Comment: As I mentioned, the token is coming correctly. And I've oauth program in the same directory & runs without issue, the problem comes at curl line

Comment: Gotya, I misread it.  Sorry about that.  When I test on my linux box, I see that I get a similar error when resp is wrapped in the $(), if I take it out, it doesn't process the first part (OAuth for you) as a literal command.  Will that work for you?